# Como guardar una imagen a un localserver con Angular y Php

Tags: php, angular7, localhost

la verdad es q no se en que le estoy errando les paso lo que hice ultimo , por intente varias cosas ya no posee errores asi q el front supongo por los console.log que esta bien  debe ser algo en el php (es un localserver sobre linux) por las dudas ,

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { UploadService } from "../../service/upload.service";

interface HtmlInputEvent extends Event {
  target: HTMLInputElement & EventTarget;
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-prom-products",
  templateUrl: "./prom-products.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./prom-products.component.css"]
})
export class PromProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  archivo = {
    nombreArchivo: null,
    base64textString: null
  };

  file: File;
  file1: File;
  file2: File;
  file3: File;
  photoSelected: string | ArrayBuffer;
  photoSelected1: string | ArrayBuffer;
  photoSelected2: string | ArrayBuffer;
  photoSelected3: string | ArrayBuffer;

  constructor(private uploadService: UploadService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onphotoSelected(event: HtmlInputEvent): void {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      this.file = <File>event.target.files[0];

      var files = event.target.files;
      var file = files[0];
      this.archivo.nombreArchivo = file.name;

      if (files && file) {
        var readerFoto = new FileReader();
        readerFoto.onload = this._handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);
        readerFoto.readAsBinaryString(file);
      }

      //imagen preview
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = e => (this.photoSelected = reader.result);
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.file);
    }
  }
  _handleReaderLoaded(readerEvent) {
    var binaryString = readerEvent.target.result;
    this.archivo.base64textString = btoa(binaryString);
  }

  onphotoSelected1(event: HtmlInputEvent): void {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      this.file1 = <File>event.target.files[0];

      //imagen preview
      const reader1 = new FileReader();
      reader1.onload = e => (this.photoSelected1 = reader1.result);
      reader1.readAsDataURL(this.file1);
    }
  }

  onphotoSelected2(event: HtmlInputEvent): void {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      this.file2 = <File>event.target.files[0];

      //imagen preview
      const reader2 = new FileReader();
      reader2.onload = e => (this.photoSelected2 = reader2.result);
      reader2.readAsDataURL(this.file2);
    }
  }
  onphotoSelected3(event: HtmlInputEvent): void {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      this.file3 = <File>event.target.files[0];

      //imagen preview
      const reader3 = new FileReader();
      reader3.onload = e => (this.photoSelected3 = reader3.result);
      reader3.readAsDataURL(this.file3);
    }
  }

  upload(
    titulo: HTMLInputElement,
    marca: HTMLInputElement,
    modelo: HTMLInputElement,
    caract: HTMLTextAreaElement
  ): boolean {
    console.log(titulo.value);
    console.log(marca.value);
    console.log(modelo.value);
    console.log(caract.value);
    console.log(this.file.name);
    console.log(this.file1.name);
    console.log(this.file2.name);
    console.log(this.file3.name);
    console.log(this.file);
    console.log(this.archivo);

    this.uploadService.uploadFile(this.archivo).subscribe(datos => {
      if (datos["resultado"] == "OK") {
        alert(datos["mensaje"]);
      }
    });

    return false;
  }
}
```

> hasta aquí el componente adjunto imagen de las repuestas en consola

y obtengo esto [image: los console.log sin error]

> y este es mi archivo php (subirArchivo.php)

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

    $json = file_get_contents('php://input'); // RECIBE EL JSON DE ANGULAR

    $params = json_decode($json); // DECODIFICA EL JSON Y LO GUARADA EN LA VARIABLE

    $nombre = $params->nombre;
    $nombreArchivo = $params->nombreArchivo;
    $archivo = $params->base64textString;
    $archivo = base64_decode($archivo);

    $filePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."http://localhost:8080/imagenesProductos/".$nombreArchivo;
    file_put_contents($filePath, $archivo);


    class Result {}

    $response = new Result();

    $response->resultado = 'OK';
    $response->mensaje = 'SE SUBIO EXITOSAMENTE';

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response); 

?>
```

> al no retornar error tendría q funcionar pero la verdad es q no sube las imágenes al servidor local
>   este es el componente desde ya gracias